# Unity Camera Background Color

Tags: unity-game-engine

In the image below, you can see my scene including a map. However in play mode, due to the color adjustment of the main camera, only a single flat color is visible. I tried to play with the color settings in any way (changing colors, transparency) but it still doesn't work.

Also, whenever I add a new scene, the camera comes with the same setting and nothing is observed in play mode. What can be the possible reasons for this problem?

[image: My setup]

Comment: Take a 3D look at the scene. It could be that the camera is behind the plane. Or anything else for that matter.
Also I can't see the main camera in your scene. Are you sure it's not in the other scene? Every scene needs it's own camera.

Comment: In order to add more details to @MrPaulch's comment: Make sure the Canvas (set in world space) is inside **the view frustum** of the camera (beyond the near plane of the camera but before the far plane). I'm not sure your canvas should be set to `World Space`, can't you use `Screen space - Overlay`?

Comment: It works now. Thank you both!